# remove lazy initializer from xjc's getter methods generated

Tags: java, jaxb, xjc

I tried to generate my POJOs using xjc and for one of my elements I have `maxOccurs="unbounded"` which will result in creating a list in the POJO:

```
public class Customer{
    private List<String> names;
    ...
    public List<String> getNames(){
        if (names == null){
            names = new ArrayList<String>();
        }
        return this.names;
    }
}
```

But I need to remove the null checking to have something like:

```
public class Customer{
    private List<String> names;
    ...
    public List<String> getNames(){
        return this.names;
    }
}
```

Then maybe in this case I need to have a setter, but it is not generated by default. Any idea?

Comment: The requirement for me is to use this POJO to generate JSON string using JAXRS, and if the list is always empty (in the first case), then it would be shown as [] . But I need it to be NULL.

Comment: I see - can you subclass it and use the subclass?